# Consume web service on IIS using windows authentication using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-services

I try to make a GET request from an Angular2 app to a web service hosted on an IIS box on the corporate network. I spent a big part of the day reading up on CORS and preflight request. I got it to the point where the server sends back a 200 response to the preflight request but when the client does the second call to actually request the resource I get `401 Unauthorized`.

I make the request like so:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'withCredentials': true });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(url, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
```

[The preflight request/response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1H5S.png)

[The following request/response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihRok.png)

I wasn't sure if I had configure the security properly on the IIS box but when I tried with a simple call using jQuery/ajax I had no issues and got the data back using (withCredentials and crossDomain being key):

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xxx:8087/odata/Users",
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
        success: function(msg) {
           ...
        },
        error: function(e){
           ...
        }
    });
```

Looking at the linked image with request/response made with TypeScript is it something obvious I'm missing to make this work?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I am having the exact same problem using windows authentication.

Comment: You could enable BASIC auth on your service in IIS, then just add the auth creds in the header of the request, or check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api